# Ubuntu screen is zoomed after installing nvidia cuda

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 version and I was installing nvidia cuda and cudnn using this link: https://ai.atamai.biz/post/install-ubuntu/

But when I rebooted, my screen became zoomed in and I can't get it back. I have tried multiple solutions online but in vain. I have uninstalled cuda but nothing changed.

Also, there is another problem, that if my device went to sleep mode, my screen just says that no device is detected and it goes black again. That means I cannot operate my device again if it goes to sleep mode. I have to unplug the cable and turn it on again!!

What should I do?